# Bokeh Plotting 'Out of range float values are not JSON compliant' Issue

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I try to build a heat map by using bokeh. However I keep getting the same error. I'll include both my code and error below, please help me out!

I assumed that the error is mainly about Nan's in my data, so I've added necessary if statements to the code to make sure that this issue is addressed. Even tried to fill any possible Na's with zero in the following lists: 'user','module','ratio','color', and 'alpha'. However none of these changes helped.

```py
colors = ['#ff0000','#ff1919','#ff4c4c','#ff7f7f','#99cc99','#7fbf7f','#4ca64c','#329932','#008000'] sorted_userlist = list(total_checks_sorted.index) user = [] module = [] ratio = [] color = [] alpha = []

for m_id in ol_module_ids:
    pset = m_id.split('/')[-1]
    col_name1 = m_id + '_ratio'
    col_name2 = m_id + '_total'
    min_checks = min(check_matrix[col_name2].values)
    max_checks = max(check_matrix[col_name2].values)
    for i, u in enumerate(sorted_userlist): 
        module.append(pset)
        user.append(str(i+1))
        ratio_value = check_matrix[col_name1][u]
        ratio.append(ratio_value)
        
        al= math.sqrt((check_matrix[col_name2][u]-min_checks+0.0001)/float(max_checks))
        if ratio_value>0.16:
            al = min(al*100,1)
        alpha.append(al)
        if np.isnan(ratio_value):
            color.append(colors[0])
        else:
            color.append(colors[int(ratio_value*8)])
    
#fill NAs in source lists with zeroes pd.Series(ratio).fillna(0).tolist()

col_source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(module = module, user = user, color=color, alpha=alpha, ratio = ratio))
#source = source.fillna('')        
#TOOLS = "resize,hover,save,pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom" TOOLS = "reset,hover,save,pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom"


p=figure(title="Ratio of Correct Checks Each Student Each Online Homework Problem",
    x_range=pset, 
    #y_range = list(reversed(sorted_userlist)),
    y_range=list(reversed(list(map(str, range(1,475))))),
    x_axis_location="above", plot_width=900, plot_height=4000,
    toolbar_location="left", tools=TOOLS)
    #axis_line_color = None)
    #outline_line_color = None)#

p.rect("module", "user", 1, 1, source=col_source,
    color="color", alpha = 'alpha', line_color=None)

show(p)
```

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a very small sample data set that reproduces this? I could tell a lot more by investigating directly.

Comment: @bigreddot data comes from check_matrix. On it's columns, there are 'ratio' and 'total' values for different module IDs. 'Ratio' columns range from 0 to 1 with Nan's in them, and the 'total' columns consist of integers having 0 sometimes. Since 'ratio' is correct check divided by total check, when the 'total' value is 0 for an observation, its 'ratio' becomes Nan. I hope this helps because this is a confidential data that's why I can't share

Comment: In such a case it's usually possible to generate completely fake data that illustrates the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

NaN values are not JSON serializable (this is a glaring deficiency in the JSON standard). You mentioned there are NaN values in the `ratio` list, which you are putting in the `ColumnDataSource` here:

```
col_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(..., ratio=ratio))
```

Since it is in the CDS, Bokeh will try to serialize it, resulting in the error. You have two options:

- If you don't actually need the numeric `ratio` values in the plot for some reason (e.g. to drive a hover tool or custom mapper or something), then just leave it out of the data source.
- If you do need to send the `ratio` values, then you must put the data into a NumPy array. Bokeh serializes NumPy arrays using a different, non-JSON approach, so it is then possible to send NaNs successfully.